# Значение столбца таблицы, получаемое пользовательской функцией, обрезается

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть функция

```
CREATE FUNCTION verbose_month(@value int)
RETURNS VARCHAR(15)
AS
BEGIN
IF @value = 1 RETURN 'Январь'
IF @value = 2 RETURN 'Февраль'
IF @value = 3 RETURN 'Март'
IF @value = 4 RETURN 'Апрель'
IF @value = 5 RETURN 'Май'
IF @value = 6 RETURN 'Июнь'
IF @value = 7 RETURN 'Июль'
IF @value = 8 RETURN 'Август'
IF @value = 9 RETURN 'Сентябрь'
IF @value = 10 RETURN 'Октябрь'
IF @value = 11 RETURN 'Ноябрь'
IF @value = 12 RETURN 'Декабрь'
RETURN ''
END
```

и запрос

```
SELECT E.name, E.type_of_building, DBO.verbose_month(R.month) AS 'Месяц', RR.volume / Res.coefficient AS 'T.y.T'
FROM Education AS E
JOIN Report AS R
ON R.reporting = E.ID
JOIN ResourceReport AS RR
ON RR.report = R.ID
JOIN Resource AS Res
ON RR.resource = Res.ID AND Res.name = 'Электричество'
```

все значения получаемые из функции обрезаются
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
но при единичном запросе все нормально

```
PRINT DBO.verbose_month(1)
-- Январь
```

Схема данных наверное не обязательна

Comment: Я бы имена месяцев находил через штатную функцию `SET LANGUAGE Russian
SELECT DATENAME(mm, GETDATE()) 'Russian Month Name'`

Comment: Спасибо, но имея лишь месяц, приходиться идти на "костыль"  
```SQL
DATENAME(mm, DATEFROMPARTS(1, R.month, 1))
```
нет ли более лаконичного решения?

Comment: Можно функцией `CHOOSE` воспользоваться (доступна начиная с SqlServer 2012), что-то наподобие `SELECT num, CHOOSE(num, N'Раз', N'Два', N'Три') AS verbose_num FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) v(num)`. Аналогично можно это в функцию обернуть.

Comment: С исходной функцией загадочно, сходу как-то даже и предположений никаких не возникает. Столбец `R.month` имеет тип _int_?

Comment: А какая версия SQL?

Comment: @i-one, да, int

Comment: Конкретно интересует - 2019 с compatibility level = 150 на БД или что-то более раннее?

Comment: @Denis Rubashkin, Microsoft SQL Server Developer (64-bit) 15.0.2070.41

Comment: Добавьте к `SELECT` запросу хинт `OPTION (USE HINT( 'DISABLE_TSQL_SCALAR_UDF_INLINING' ))`. Помогло?

Comment: @Denis Rubashkin, да, помогло, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В MS SQL 2019 была добавлена возможность инлайна для скалярных пользовательских функций.

[Scalar UDF Inlining](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver15) - зачем, как и почему.

Но, к сожалению, новый функционал богат на неприятные "нюансы".

По ссылке выше в том числе описаны способы отключить Scalar UDF Inlining:

Для всей БД, команда:

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET TSQL_SCALAR_UDF_INLINING = OFF;
```

Для конкретного запроса, хинт:

```
OPTION (USE HINT('DISABLE_TSQL_SCALAR_UDF_INLINING'));
```

Дополнительно рекомендую поддерживать актуальность версии сервера, так как каждый очередной CU содержит широкий набор исправлений.

SQL Server build version 15.0.2070.41 вышел **04.11.2019**.

Актуальный 15.0.4033.1 - **31.03.2020**

Возможно, без заморочек с включением/выключением Scalar UDF Inlining поможет явная конвертация результата функции к ожидаемому типу:

```
CREATE FUNCTION verbose_month(@value int)
RETURNS VARCHAR(15)
AS
BEGIN
IF @value = 1 RETURN CONVERT( VARCHAR(15), 'Январь' )
IF @value = 2 RETURN CONVERT( VARCHAR(15), 'Февраль' )
IF @value = 3 RETURN CONVERT( VARCHAR(15), 'Март' )
IF @value = 4 RETURN CONVERT( VARCHAR(15), 'Апрель' )
IF @value = 5 RETURN CONVERT( VARCHAR(15), 'Май' )
IF @value = 6 RETURN CONVERT( VARCHAR(15), 'Июнь' )
IF @value = 7 RETURN CONVERT( VARCHAR(15), 'Июль' )
IF @value = 8 RETURN CONVERT( VARCHAR(15), 'Август' )
IF @value = 9 RETURN CONVERT( VARCHAR(15), 'Сентябрь' )
IF @value = 10 RETURN CONVERT( VARCHAR(15), 'Октябрь' )
IF @value = 11 RETURN CONVERT( VARCHAR(15), 'Ноябрь' )
IF @value = 12 RETURN CONVERT( VARCHAR(15), 'Декабрь' )
RETURN CONVERT( VARCHAR(15), '' )
END
```